# Resize LVM partition?

Tags: partitioning, disk, lvm

I have a 1023G TB LVM partition on /dev/sda5, a partition that is exactly the same on /dev/sda2 with an ID of 5 and labeled an "extended partition". /dev/sda is 1.8 TB. Finally, I have a /dev/mapper/files--vg-root which is 1022.5 GiB and a LVM swap wich is 1GiB

So how might I go about resizing either of there partitions as I don't know which one is the actual LVM partition.

Thanks!

Comment: `/dev/sda2` is an [extended partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types); it does not contain data directly, but serves as a container for logical partitions.  Inside the extended partition `/dev/sda2` lives `/dev/sda5`, which is a logical partition, formatted as an LVM physical disk. On this physical disk you have an LVM volume group containing two logical volumes, one for the root filesystem and the other used as a swap area. You did not say what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using GUI to resize partition. Try KDE Partition Manager 3.0 which can see LVM partitions.

You can get it on [Neon Live CD](https://neon.kde.org/download) (User edition is enought now)

Then open terminal and install partitionmanager:

```
apt update; apt install partitionmanager
```